# Using UserControls within a ASPX View in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, user-controls, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm in the process of migrating a traditional ASP.NET Web Form app to ASP.NET MVC 4. I've been migrating this project over by adding new Views to my ASP.NET MVC 4 project that use the ASPX view engine. I then take the code-behind content and put it in a `<script language="CS" runat="server">` within the view file.

My Web Forms project makes use of UserControls for the reusable components. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to bring these over to my new MVC 4 project.

Can someone please tell or show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did u tried changing "Inherits System.Web.UI.Page" to " Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" to make it a view!!!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. A UserControl in Web Forms derives from System.Web.UI.UserControl not System.Web.UI.Page.